# pendrive was working well on tablet, before formating..but now not showing data

Tags: tablet, usb-peripherals

My 8 GB pendrive was working well on my android 2.3 tablet, before formating..but now not showing data on usb through tablet(but showing all files on PC/Laptop); Yesterday I've formated that pendrive in NTFS file system after that it is not showing usb data(detecting usb-but no data; I again re-formated using FAT32 file system then also tablet is not showing data through USB/pendrive...
Need your help ...

Answer (score -1):

use partition manager. make partition in un-allocated space of pen drive then save the same. now pen drive works.